# Angular UI-Grid accepting null values even if type:'number"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

[Ui-grid edit documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable), here is the link for official documentation of ui-grid edit feature. Its accepting null values even if the data-type is number or string. Please let me know what should I do so that after edit, field should not accept null values if data-type is number or string

Answer (score 0):

You can do you own editableCell template and make the validations that you need. Here you have an example of cell template that is checking if the user has inserted a value or if the value is inside a range of values for a number input type:

```
<div>
<form novalidate name="inputForm">
    <input type="INPUT_TYPE" step="0.01" ng-class="'colt' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" min=0 max=100 required>
    <div ng-show="inputForm.$error.max || inputForm.$error.min || inputForm.$error.required" class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="errorMessageBox" ng-show="inputForm.$error.required">
        <div class="errorMessageBoxContent">Required field</div>
    </div>
    <div class="errorMessageBox" ng-show="inputForm.$error.min">
        <div class="errorMessageBoxContent">The impact must be greater than 0%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="errorMessageBox" ng-show="inputForm.$error.max">
        <div  class="errorMessageBoxContent">The impact must be less than 100%</div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

And here you have the definition of the column:

```
{
 headerCellClass: 'header-main',
 displayName: 'IMPACT',
 headerCellFilter: 'translate',
 field: 'equivalentImpact',
 width: 180,
 enableCellEdit: $sessionStorage.currentUser.isAdmin,
 type: "number",
 editableCellTemplate: require("./editableImpact.html")
}
```

Comment: Thanks can you give that in a plnkr it would be very helpful for me